# What does the saying, "I don't like to eat what I can't swallow" mean?

Tags: expressions, popular-refrains, euphemisms

My friend said this to me in regards to his girlfriend being older than he is.  I don't understand what the saying means.

Comment: There is a more common idiom "hard to swallow".  You might want to look it up.

Comment: @HotLicks Who knows what's in this guy's head, but to me it seems to have the pattern of a saying going extreme. i.e. eat/bite off ...  chew/swallow. Whatever. I think it is a funny question, and will retract my VTC.

Comment: It might depend on what age the people are.

Comment: Welcome to SE!  This is not a common saying. In order to answer, we need to know what was said before this. What was the conversation? Did he say this is response to a remark by someone else?  Did you or someone else criticise him for having an older girlfriend?

Comment: Can you provide more context? I can think of a few options, but they aren’t related to her age.

Comment: Eating includes swallowing, doesn’t it? So this really doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Seems to me that to swallow means to accept  and he can’t accept (come to grips with) the fact that she’s older.  He could never marry her (to commit / swallow) . And so he’s having a hard time even just dating her.    But that’s a lot of speculation off very minimal information.

Comment: It's a reference perhaps to boa constrictors, which swallow their prey whole.  As others have mentioned, given the context of age difference, the interpretation can be varied.

Answer (score 3):

***"eat what  I can't  swallow"***

as a saying seems to be a nonce. Other than nonsense [such as this](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=eat%20what%20I%20can%27t%20swallow), I cannot find any other cases.

Searches render suggestions such as these.

> When eating food, you first bite off a piece, then chew it, and swallow it. **If you bite off more than you can chew**, you have taken a bite so large that you are not able chew it. Example: "I went skiing last weekend and I went down the most difficult hill first.

Obviously the reference is:

***to bite off more than I can chew***

> To bite off more than you can chew is to take on more responsibility than you can handle;

[-Idioms-online](https://www.idioms.online/bite-off-more-than-you-can-chew/)

So,

> "*eat more than I can swallow*"

**may be  a more extreme paraphrasing of the older saying: i.e.  You can chew it, but maybe not swallow. You can bite it, but maybe not eat.**

On the other hand..it may refer to

***hard to swallow***

> difficult to believe:

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard-to-swallow)

In other words,  he cannot accept the fact.

Comment: This is starting to sound a little like a Steven King novel I once read....

Comment: I can support *to bite off more than I can chew*

Comment: @Greybeard ...as opposed to "hard to swallow"? I was trying to cover the bases. Language is a Cuckoo bird sometimes.

Comment: Yes. "hard to swallow" = hard to believe/accept.

Comment: TXS @Greybeard I will sleep on it. Happy Friday 13th.